# Moving a column around in python

Tags: python

i have never used python before, but for a school unit i think i should learn it, i have a cypher text to break, and thanks to some help on here, i have gotten a brute force attack on a transosition to work :)

what i want to try and to next is instead of just trying all the possible grid sizes, i also now want to try out all the different column variations as well

```
ICBKAOREMDERAEAA
```

which is i am a code breaker,

to crack this by hand i had to set up a 4 x 4 grid

```
I C B K
A O R E
M D E R
A E A A
```

i can achieve this with the code :

```
s = "ICBKAOREMDERAEAA"
for i in range(1, len(s) + 1): # range doesn't include upper bound
    rows = [s[x:x+i] for x in range(0, len(s), i)]
    #print('\n'.join(rows))
    columns = list(zip(*rows))
    print columns
```

but what i want to do is now, try every column combination, so for the above it would also try :

```
C B K I
O R E A
D E R M
E A A A
```

so it would move the front column to the back etc

what would i need to add to my code for this to complete this task ?

Thanks guys

Comment: basically you can solve your problem with the following: s[0::4], s[1::4], s[2::4], s[3::4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string slicing to get the separate lists.

```
import math

encoded_txt = "ICBKAOREMDERAEAA"
GRIDSIZE = int(math.sqrt(len(encoded_txt)))
columns = [encoded_txt[i::GRIDSIZE] for i in range(GRIDSIZE)]

>>> columns
['IAMA', 'CODE', 'BREA', 'KERA']
```

Then use itertools to find all permutations

```
>>>import itertools

>>>for permutation in itertools.permutations(columns):
       print(''.join(permutation))
IAMACODEBREAKERA
IAMACODEKERABREA
IAMABREACODEKERA
IAMABREAKERACODE
IAMAKERACODEBREA
IAMAKERABREACODE
CODEIAMABREAKERA
CODEIAMAKERABREA
CODEBREAIAMAKERA
CODEBREAKERAIAMA
CODEKERAIAMABREA
CODEKERABREAIAMA
BREAIAMACODEKERA
BREAIAMAKERACODE
BREACODEIAMAKERA
BREACODEKERAIAMA
BREAKERAIAMACODE
BREAKERACODEIAMA
KERAIAMACODEBREA
KERAIAMABREACODE
KERACODEIAMABREA
KERACODEBREAIAMA
KERABREAIAMACODE
KERABREACODEIAMA
```

Now if you only want to get the permutations that are still in column order, I'd write a new bit of code:

```
def orderedpermutations(lst):
    from copy import copy # possibly deepcopy, but unnecessary for this implementation
    new_list = copy(lst)
    for _ in range(len(new_list)):
        new_list.append(new_list.pop(0))
        yield new_list
```

Then you can use that as a generator:

```
for permutation in orderedpermutations(columns):
    print(permutation)
```

Comment: SOrry how do i use the itertools ? i am completly new to python

Comment: I actually don't use `itertools` very often so I had to consult the documentation. I did edit with the relevant code.

Comment: No problem, but don't settle for getting the right answer! The key to becoming a good programmer is to understand how code works. Dig into the documentation for `itertools`. Think deeply about how else you could use the string slicing technique I used. If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks i will, only question is if i had a large input `tooitaoulguphnlceiagggtceotaensehoiyntidsonngitiludketuoiyiiecshimrphuwnetnboalhegghrnreqohegkrrrtwtac` but i new the size of the grid would be 6 columns how many answers should i get as i have tried running the code with columns = 6 but it has been 10 mins so far and still runningthrough combinations !

Comment: @user2292674 encoded text that size with that column length would have 355,687,428,096,000 permutations -- that is to say `len(list(itertools.permutations(columns)))` exceeds 355.5 TRILLION. Yeah, it may take SOME TIME.

Comment: If you don't need to get ALL permutations, and only every SEQUENTIAL permutation (e.g. `[[A,B,C,D], [B,C,D,A], [C,D,A,B], [D,A,B,C]]` but never `[A,C,B,D]` then this becomes easier to solve with slices again.

Comment: That said, nothing appears to be decrypted with either interpretation of your "6 columns" (either 6 columns of 17 chars or 17 columns of 6 chars) Is this just sample text or should there be something there?